# Total number of string objects in memory

Tags: c#, .net, string

Can anybody please tell me the total number of string instances created in memory for below example ? 
Brief explanation would be appreciated a lot.

My code:

```
 String A = "1" + "2" + "3" ;  /* total number of strings in memory = ?? */

 String B = "1" + "2" + "1" ;  /* total number of strings in memory = ?? */

 string one = "1";

 string two = "2";

 string three = "3";

 String C = one + two + three;   /* total number of strings in memory = ?? */

 String D = one + two + one;    /* total number of strings in memory = ?? */
```

Comment: Either 3 or 7, depending on whether you include both "string" and "String"

Comment: @Rariolu - string and String are the same.

Comment: Well, yeah, but y'know :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [C# documentation on string concatenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx):

> When you concatenate string literals or string constants by using the + operator, the compiler creates a single string. No run time concatenation occurs.

This means that your concatenations create only one string each, so in total your example produces 7 strings in memory:

```
String A = "1" + "2" + "3" ;  // 1 (concatenation of literals)
String B = "1" + "2" + "1" ;  // 1 (concatenation of literals)

string one = "1"; // 1
string two = "2"; // 1
string three = "3"; // 1

String C = one + two + three; // 1 (concatenation of string constants)
String D = one + two + one; // 1 (concatenation of string constants)

// = 7 strings in total
```

However, if doing the concatenation in a loop, more strings are generated, e.g.:

```
for word in text:
    result_string += word // Bad! Creates a new string in each iteration
```

In this case it is better to use [`StringBuilder.append`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4sc8ca8.aspx):

```
System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
for word in text:
    builder.Append(word) // Good! Just appends to the string builder
```

Comment: your second code is the same as the first, but I catch your drift :)

Comment: `one` , `two` and `three` are not constants, they are variables. That doesn't affect the count though.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look code IL in the IL DASM

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       54 (0x36)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init ([0] string A,
           [1] string B,
           [2] string one,
           [3] string two,
           [4] string three,
           [5] string C,
           [6] string D)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "123"
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldstr      "121"
  IL_000c:  stloc.1
  IL_000d:  ldstr      "1"
  IL_0012:  stloc.2
  IL_0013:  ldstr      "2"
  IL_0018:  stloc.3
  IL_0019:  ldstr      "3"
  IL_001e:  stloc.s    three
  IL_0020:  ldloc.2
  IL_0021:  ldloc.3
  IL_0022:  ldloc.s    three
  IL_0024:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,
                                                              string,
                                                              string)
  IL_0029:  stloc.s    C
  IL_002b:  ldloc.2
  IL_002c:  ldloc.3
  IL_002d:  ldloc.2
  IL_002e:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,
                                                              string,
                                                              string)
  IL_0033:  stloc.s    D
  IL_0035:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

As you can see, there are 5 string constants

> "123", "121", "1", "2", "3"

and two strings obtained by concatenation. Total 7.

Although A and C (B and D) strings are the same, but they are different instances in memory.

---

To Arghya C.

If we apply the unsafe code and change the value of the variable A:

```
Console.WriteLine(A + " " + C);

fixed (char* p = A)
{
    p[1] = 'x';
}

Console.WriteLine(A + " " + C);
```

we get the following output:

> 123 123
>   1x3 123

As you can see, only the variable A has changed, but the C variable retained its value. This proves that they are different copies.

However, if we write this:

```
String A = "1" + "2" + "3";
String C = "123";
```

аfter executing unsafe code above we get the following:

> 123 123
>   1x3 1x3

That is, in this case, the variables A and C keeps a reference to the same instance of the string.

At first I wrote the wrong answer, because I thought the compiler is smart enough to understand at compile-time that `String C = one + two + three;` concatenates constants and will create reference on the same string.

Comment: Alexander you didn't mention two string that are returned by `Concat` method invokation so it's actually 7 strings, not 5

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov From your answer, it seems like there will be only 5 string instances. Can you please update your answer and explain how there are 7 strings? Thanks!

Comment: @Fabjan Are you saying there will be seven string instances (A, B, one, two, three, C, D) but they will actually refer to 5 memory locations (C,D pointing to A,B) ?

Comment: @ArghyaC - please, see update. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Thanks for the explanation! And your English is fine :)